# Is their a way to change the selected index of a picker from a button click on another page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

So i am trying to change the selected index of my picker when a user clicks on button on a different page. The user is able to click on a certain doctor from a list view which then directs them to the add appointment page. From here there is a drop down list auto populated with all the users doctors. The dropdown remains blank until the user picks which doctor they want.

Is it possible to change the selected index of doctor dropdown to match the doctor in the list from the previous page once the button is clicked ?

[image][image]
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Beginner in Xamarin

Comment: it's hard to give a specific answer without seeing your code, but of course you can do this.  Just pass the selected value from the first page to the 2nd page via it's constructor, then in the OnAppearing of the 2nd page set the value of the picker appropriately

Comment: Thank you mate, that did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jason is right here. you can pass the index to the new page and in `OnAppearing` set `SelectedIndex = passedIndex` in your view model. This is if you have `SelectedIndex` bound to a property in your view model.

if you're using `SelectedItem` you'll need to  find the doctor object and use that to set `SelectedItem` in your view model. ex. `SelectedItem = DoctorList.IndexOf(passedIndex)` or if passing the doctor object `SelectedItem = DoctorList.First(doc => doc.Id == passedDoc.Id)`.